# Glassfish Java error when deploying WAR

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, liferay

I have two Java SDKs installed. How do I find out which one Glassfishv3 is using? I am getting several Java EE errors when I try to deploy WAR files.

Below is an example of an error when I try deploying a WAR:

```
Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAutoProxyCreator#0' defined in class path resource [META-INF/base-spring.xml]:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting this in your application somewhere, log (or otherwise get access to) the result:

System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));

Comment: There is probably a place in Glassfish that tells you what Java path it is referencing..

Comment: I wouldn't doubt it being in a log or something, and it is configured somehow (we just don't know where to look), so if nobody knows a simpler solution, this shouldn't be hard to do just to get the question answered and move on...